# Authentication Flow: How to use API

Tags: node.js

This flow is confusing me a bit and I would appreciate any help/diagram/flow-chart that could help me understand this better:

As an example, I would like to access Google's API. The thing is what I want to access sits on an enterprise account and to even get to use any of Google Suite Applications, I have to log in to my work account (SSO.) On top of that, all this needs to be done via VPN.

I've used Puppeteer for this in Node.js, and though it works on my machine, It stops working if I try to host it anywhere else because (I assume) due to the VPN issue. It's clunky and just plain hack-ish because I'm just automating what I normally do on the browser.

What are the best practices in being able to use Google's API? What does the algorithm look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'googleapis' package on npm
https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

here is an example...

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const bigquery = google.bigquery('v2');

async function main() {

  // This method looks for the GCLOUD_PROJECT and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
  // environment variables.
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  });
  const authClient = await auth.getClient();

  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();

  const request = {
    projectId,
    datasetId: '<YOUR_DATASET_ID>',

    // This is a "request-level" option
    auth: authClient
  };

  const res = await bigquery.datasets.delete(request);
  console.log(res.data);

}

main().catch(console.error);
```

you can use a proxy by setting the `process.env.http` or `process.env.https`environment variables to solve your vpn issue

Comment: Thank you @Dylan, but I'm actually looking for a broader understanding of the authentication flow instead of using a library.